# How to distribute People Search Core Results over two columns using XSL

Tags: xslt

I would be grateful if someone can show me how I would rewrite the following XSL file to produce the following layout (I have removed the Parameter lines in the code to meet the max character requirements):

1 | 2

3 | 4

5 | 6

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" 
    xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" 
    xmlns:SEARCHWC="http://schemas.microsoft.com/searchserver/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
    <!-- PARAMETER LINES REMOVED TO SHORTEN CODE TO ACCEPTED LENGTH -->

    <!-- When there is no keywory to issue the search -->
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.noKeyword">
      <span class="ms-sbplain">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$IsFixedQuery">
            <xsl:value-of select="$NoFixedQuery" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$NoKeyword" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </span>       
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- When empty result set is returned from search -->
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.empty">  
      <div class="psrch-results">
        <xsl:if test="$ShowActionLinks">
          <xsl:call-template name="ActionBarTemplate" />
        </xsl:if>
      </div>

      <span class="srch-description" id="CSR_NO_RESULTS">
        <xsl:value-of select="$NoPeopleResults"/>
        <ol>
          <li><xsl:value-of select="$NoPeopleResults1"/></li>
          <li><xsl:value-of select="$NoPeopleResults2"/></li>
          <li><xsl:value-of select="$NoPeopleResults3"/></li>
          <li><xsl:value-of select="$NoPeopleResults4"/></li>
        </ol>
      </span>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Main body template-->
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
      <div class="psrch-results">
        <xsl:if test="$ShowActionLinks">
          <div class="srch-sort-right2"> 
            <xsl:if test="$LangPickerNodeSet and count($LangPickerNodeSet) &gt; 0">
              <label for="langpickerdd" id="langpickerddlabel"><xsl:value-of select="$LangPickerHeading"/></label>
              <select title="{$LangPickerHeading}" class="srch-dropdown" onchange="window.location.href=this.value" id="langpickerdd">
                <xsl:for-each select="$LangPickerNodeSet">
                  <xsl:element name="option">
                    <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="@url"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:if test="@selected = 'true'">
                      <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>        
              </select>
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#8195;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="$ShowPeopleSortDropdown">
              <label for="sortbydd" id="sortbyddlabel"><xsl:value-of select="$SortBy" /></label> 
              <select title="{$SortBy}" name="dropdown" onchange="window.location.href=this.value" class="srch-dropdown" id="sortbydd">
                <xsl:element name="option"> 
                  <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string($RelevanceSortUrl))"/></xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:if test="$DropDownOption = '0'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$RelevanceSortLabel"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:if test="string-length($SocialDistanceSortUrl) &gt; 0 and string-length($SocialDistanceSortLabel) &gt; 0">
                  <xsl:element name="option"> 
                    <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string($SocialDistanceSortUrl))"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:if test="$DropDownOption = '1'">
                      <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$SocialDistanceSortLabel"/>
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:element name="option"> 
                  <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string($NameSortUrl))"/></xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:if test="$DropDownOption = '2'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$NameSortLabel"/>
                </xsl:element>
              </select>  
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#8195;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:call-template name="ActionBarTemplate" />
          </div>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:for-each select="All_Results/Result">
          <xsl:call-template name="SingleResult"/>
        </xsl:for-each>    
        <xsl:call-template name="MoreLinkTemplate" />
      </div>  
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- This template is called for each result -->
    <xsl:template name="SingleResult">  
      <xsl:element name="div"> 
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('Container', id)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="id = 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">psrch-FirstFullResult</xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">psrch-FullResult</xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:call-template name="SingleResultInternal" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="SingleResultInternal">
      <xsl:variable name="id" select="id"/>
      <xsl:variable name="currentId" select="concat($IdPrefix,$id)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="url" select="url"/>
      <xsl:variable name="email" select="workemail"/>
      <xsl:variable name="sip" select="sipaddress"/>
      <xsl:variable name="prefix">IMNRC('</xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="suffix">')</xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="hassip"       select="string-length($sip) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasemail"     select="string-length($email) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="haspn"        select="string-length(preferredname) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasydn"       select="string-length(yomidisplayname) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasjt"        select="string-length(jobtitle) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasdp"        select="string-length(department) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasorg"       select="string-length(orgnames) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="haswph"       select="string-length(workphone) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasonum"      select="string-length(officenumber) &gt; 0"/>

      <xsl:variable name="hascol"       select="string-length(colleaguecategory) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasacu"       select="string-length(addtomycolleaguesurl) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hashier"      select="string-length(hierarchyurl) &gt; 0"/>

      <xsl:variable name="hasabme"      select="string-length(aboutme) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasresp"      select="string-length(responsibility) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hassk"        select="($FilterNodeSet and $FilterNodeSet/@title='SPShSkills') or hithighlightedproperties/skills/@hashh &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasint"       select="($FilterNodeSet and $FilterNodeSet/@title='SPShInterests') or hithighlightedproperties/interests/@hashh &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasorgparent" select="($FilterNodeSet and $FilterNodeSet/@title='OrgParentNames') or hithighlightedproperties/orgparentnames/@hashh &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasmem"       select="($FilterNodeSet and $FilterNodeSet/@title='Memberships') or hithighlightedproperties/memberships/@hashh &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="haspp"        select="($FilterNodeSet and $FilterNodeSet/@title='SPShPastProjects') or hithighlightedproperties/pastprojects/@hashh &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasbol"       select="($FilterNodeSet and $FilterNodeSet/@title='SPShLocation') or hithighlightedproperties/baseofficelocation/@hashh &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hassch"       select="($FilterNodeSet and $FilterNodeSet/@title='SPShSchool') or hithighlightedproperties/schools/@hashh &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hassum"       select="count(hithighlightedsummary/c0) &gt; 0"/>

      <xsl:variable name="hasvlm"       select="string-length(profileviewlastmonth) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasvlw"       select="string-length(profileviewlastweek) &gt; 0"/>
      <xsl:variable name="hasquery"     select="string-length(queriesfoundyou) &gt; 0"/>

      <div id="UserPhoto">
        <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string($url))}" id="{concat($currentId, '_CSR_IMGL')}" title="{preferredname}">
          <xsl:variable name="imgid" select="concat('CSR_IMG_',$id)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="purl">
            <xsl:call-template name="GetPicUrl">
              <xsl:with-param name="PicUrl" select="pictureurl"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="PlaceHolderUrl" select="'/_layouts/images/o14_person_placeholder_96.png'"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:variable>
          <img id="{$imgid}" src="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string($purl))}" alt="{preferredname}" border="0"></img>
        </a>
        <xsl:if test="$hascol">
          <div id="ColleagueField">
            <xsl:value-of select="colleaguecategory"/>
          </div>
        </xsl:if>
      </div>
      <span id="JBean">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$hassip">
            <img alt="" border="0" height="12" width="12" src="/_layouts/images/imnhdr.gif" onload="{concat($prefix, $sip, $suffix)}" ShowOfflinePawn="1" id="{concat('CSRP_',$id,',type=sip')}" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <img alt="" border="0" height="12" width="12" src="/_layouts/images/imnhdr.gif" onload="{concat($prefix, $email, $suffix)}" ShowOfflinePawn="1" id="{concat('CSRP_',$id,',type=smtp')}" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </span>
      <div id="ContactInfo">
        <ul id="MiniContactCard">
          <li id="NameField">
            <xsl:if test="$haspn">
              <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string($url))}" id="{concat($currentId, '_CSR')}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/preferredname" />
              </a>
            </xsl:if>
          </li>
          <xsl:if test="$hasydn">
            <li id="YomiField">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/yomidisplayname" />
            </li>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$hasjt">
            <li id="JobTitleField">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/jobtitle" />
            </li>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$hasdp and not($hasorg)">
            <li id="DepartmentField">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/department" />
            </li>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$hasorg">
            <li id="OrgField">                    
              <xsl:call-template name="RenderNameUrlMultivalue">
                <xsl:with-param name="names" select="hithighlightedproperties/orgnames"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="urls" select="orgurls_multival"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="currentId" select="$currentId"/>
              </xsl:call-template>          
            </li>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$haswph">
            <li id="PhoneField">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/workphone" />
            </li>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$hasonum">
            <li id="OfficeField">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/officenumber" />
            </li>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$hassip or $hasemail">
            <li id="EmailField">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$hassip">
                  <a id="{concat($currentId, '_EmailLink')}" href="{concat('mailto:', $sip)}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/sipaddress" />
                  </a>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <a id="{concat($currentId, '_EmailLink')}" href="{concat('mailto:', $email)}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/workemail" />
                  </a>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </li>
          </xsl:if>
        </ul>

        <xsl:if test="$hasacu or $hashier or $IsPeopleCoreResultsWebPart">
          <ul id="Actions">        
            <xsl:if test="$hasacu">
              <li id="AddColleagueLinkField">
                <a id="{concat($currentId, '_AddColleagueLink')}" href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string(addtomycolleaguesurl))}">&#187; <xsl:value-of select="$AddToMyColleaguesText" /></a>
              </li>
          </xsl:if>
          </ul>
        </xsl:if>
      </div>

      <xsl:if test="$hasabme or $hasresp or $hassk or $hasint or $hasorgparent or $hasmem or $haspp or $hassch or $hasbol or $hassum">
        <div id="MoreInfo">
          <ul>        
            <xsl:if test="$hasabme">
              <li>
                <span id="FieldTitle">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$AboutMeLabel" />
                </span>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/aboutme" />
              </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$hasresp">
              <li>
                <span id="FieldTitle">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$ResponsibilitiesLabel" />
                </span>          
                <xsl:call-template name="RenderSimpleMultivalue">
                  <xsl:with-param name="multivalue" select="hithighlightedproperties/responsibility"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="cutoff" select="5"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
              </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$hassk">
              <li>
                <span id="FieldTitle">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$SkillsLabel" />
                </span>          
                <xsl:call-template name="RenderSimpleMultivalue">
                  <xsl:with-param name="multivalue" select="hithighlightedproperties/skills"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="cutoff" select="5"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
              </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$hasint">
              <li>
                <span id="FieldTitle">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$InterestsLabel" />
                </span>          
                <xsl:call-template name="RenderSimpleMultivalue">
                  <xsl:with-param name="multivalue" select="hithighlightedproperties/interests"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="cutoff" select="5"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
              </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$hasorgparent">
              <li>            
                <span id="FieldTitle">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$ParentOrgsLabel" />
                </span>          
                <span id="HotHH">
                  <xsl:call-template name="RenderNameUrlMultivalue">
                    <xsl:with-param name="names" select="hithighlightedproperties/orgparentnames"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="urls" select="orgparenturls_multival"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="currentId" select="$currentId"/>
                  </xsl:call-template>
                </span>
              </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$hasmem">
              <li>
                <span id="FieldTitle">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$MembershipLabel" />
                </span>          
                <xsl:call-template name="RenderSimpleMultivalue">
                  <xsl:with-param name="multivalue" select="hithighlightedproperties/memberships"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="cutoff" select="5"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
              </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$haspp">
              <li>
                <span id="FieldTitle">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$PastProjectsLabel" />
                </span>          
                <xsl:call-template name="RenderSimpleMultivalue">
                  <xsl:with-param name="multivalue" select="hithighlightedproperties/pastprojects"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="cutoff" select="5"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
              </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$hassch">
              <li>
                <span id="FieldTitle">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$SchoolLabel" />
                </span>          
                <xsl:call-template name="RenderSimpleMultivalue">
                  <xsl:with-param name="multivalue" select="hithighlightedproperties/schools"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="cutoff" select="5"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
              </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$hasbol">
              <li>
                <span id="FieldTitle">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$BaseOfficeLabel" />
                </span>          
                <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedproperties/baseofficelocation" />
              </li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$hassum">
              <li>
                <span id="FieldTitle">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$SummaryLabel" />
                </span>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="hithighlightedsummary" />
              </li>
            </xsl:if>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>

      <div id="Clear">
        <img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt=''/>
      </div>
    </xsl:template>  

    <!-- XSL transformation starts here -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:if test="$AlertMeLink and $ShowActionLinks">  
       <input type="hidden" name="P_Query" />
       <input type="hidden" name="P_LastNotificationTime" />
      </xsl:if>

      <div class="psrch-Main">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$IsNoKeyword = 'True'" >
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.noKeyword" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="$ShowMessage = 'True'">
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.empty" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body"/>      
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:if test="$IsPeopleCoreResultsWebPart and (count(All_Results/Result) &gt; 0 or count(All_Results/FakeResult) &gt; 0)">
         <asp:Panel ID="PopupPanelPeopleCore" runat="server" CssClass="psrch-PopupPanel">                
            <div id="PopupContainer" class="psrch-PopupContainer">          
              <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelPeopleCore" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                <ContentTemplate>              
                  <SEARCHWC:PeopleCoreResultPopupControl
            id="PopupControl51A944753DF0430C8FE1EBAA70F3E945"
                    runat="server"/>

                  <div id="PopupFooter">
                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" DisplayAfter="0" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelPeopleCore" runat="server">
                      <ProgressTemplate>
                        <span id="Progress">
                          <img class="psrch-UpdateGraphics" src="/_layouts/images/hig_progcircle_loading24.gif"/>
                          <xsl:value-of select="$PopupFetcingResultLabel" />
                        </span>                  
                      </ProgressTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                  </div>
                </ContentTemplate>            
              </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
          </asp:Panel>
        </xsl:if>   

      </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ActionBarTemplate">
      <xsl:if test="string-length($AlertMeLink) &gt; 0">  
        <a href="{$AlertMeLink}" id="CSR_AM" title="{$AlertMeText}">
          <img src="/_layouts/images/bell.gif" alt="{$AlertMeText}" border="0"/>
        </a>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#8195;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="string-length($SrchRSSLink) &gt; 0">     
        <a type="application/rss+xml" href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string($SrchRSSLink))}" title="{$SrchRSSText}" id="SRCHRSSL">
          <img border="0" src="/_layouts/images/rss.gif" alt="{$SrchRSSText}"/>
        </a>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#8195;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>

      <xsl:if test="string-length($SearchProviderLink) &gt; 0">  
        <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string($SearchProviderLink))}" title="{$SearchProviderText}" >
          <img border="0" src="/_layouts/images/searchfolder.png" alt="{$SearchProviderText}"/>
        </a>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#8195;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="GetPicUrl">
      <xsl:param name="PicUrl"/>
      <xsl:param name="PlaceHolderUrl"/>  
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($PicUrl) &lt; 1 or starts-with($PicUrl, 'file:') or starts-with($PicUrl, '\\') or starts-with($PicUrl, '//')">
          <xsl:value-of select="$PlaceHolderUrl"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$PicUrl"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="MoreLinkTemplate">
      <xsl:if test="$ShowMoreLink = true() and string-length($MoreLink) &gt; 0">
        <div id="MoreLink">
          <a href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string($MoreLink))}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$MoreLinkLabel"/>
          </a>
        </div>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="RenderNameUrlMultivalue">
      <xsl:param name="names"/>
      <xsl:param name="urls"/>
      <xsl:param name="currentId"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$names">
        <xsl:variable name="p" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length(.) &gt; 0">
         <xsl:if test="$p &gt; 1">
            <span class="psrch-TextSeparator"> :: </span>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($urls[$p]) &gt; 0">
              <a id="{concat($currentId, '_MultivalueUrl')}" href="{ddwrt:EnsureAllowedProtocol(string($urls[$p]))}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
              </a>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>        
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="RenderSimpleMultivalue">
      <xsl:param name="multivalue"/>
      <xsl:param name="cutoff"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="$multivalue">
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending" select="@hashh"/>
        <xsl:variable name="p" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length(.) &gt; 0">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$p = 1">
              <span id="Multivalue">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
              </span>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$p &gt; 1 and $p &lt;= $cutoff">
              <span class="psrch-TextSeparator"> :: </span>
              <span id="Multivalue"><xsl:apply-templates select="." /></span>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$p = $cutoff + 1">
              &#8230;
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="HitHighlighting"> 
     <xsl:param name="hh" /> 
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$hh"/> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ddd"> 
      &#8230;  
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="c0"> 
        <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="c1"> 
        <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="c2"> 
        <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="c3"> 
        <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="c4"> 
        <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="c5"> 
        <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="c6"> 
        <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="c7"> 
        <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="c8"> 
        <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="c9"> 
    <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
    </xsl:template> 

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You will have a much better chance of getting an answer if you can keep the question as short and direct as possible. See the [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) for general 

guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have now stripped my question down to the bare minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't recall if the People Search XSL contains a Current Position parameter. But if it does, XSL has a method called [`mod`](http://www17.homepage.villanova.edu/william.pohlhaus/xsl/mod/) which is commonly used to alternate item display.

Example:

```
...
<xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
    <!-- Your HTML for items -->
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
    <!-- Your HTML for alternating items -->
</xsl:if>
...
```

This way you can with the help of HTML and CSS change how to display the search results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll see if I can implement it.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have tried to implement your code with some success, but I'm sure I'm positioning the code incorrectly.

Can you show me where this code would sit within a simple table with two columns, each table cell holding a "SingleResult" template reference?

Thanks for your help, I think I'm much closer to getting the results I need with your advice! :-)

Answer (score 0):

with the use of your code, I was finally able to produce the formatting results I wanted.  Below is the XSL I used:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="All_Results/Result">
         <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
              <div style="width:50%;float:left;"><xsl:call-template name="SingleResult"/></div>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
              <div style="width:50%;float:right;"><xsl:call-template name="SingleResult"/></div>            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Luke T-

How did you get this to work?

When I try this

```
    <xsl:for-each select="All_Results/Result">
         <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
              <div style="width:50%;float:left;"><xsl:call-template name="SingleResult"/></div>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
              <div style="width:50%;float:right;"><xsl:call-template name="SingleResult"/></div>            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I end up with
1 
    2
3
    4

Comment: this is not an answer, next time please use comments.

Comment: Hi Shawn,  sorry for not replying earlier - I've been on holiday.

Dave Paylor's answer on your 'redux' thread should work very nicely.  The solution I ended up using was probably overkill.