# How to distribute People Search Core Results over two columns using XSL redux

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, xslt

This is a follow up to [How to distribute People Search Core Results over two columns using XSL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/68478/how-to-distribute-people-search-core-results-over-two-columns-using-xsl/),

When I use the suggested code block in that article

```
    <xsl:for-each select="All_Results/Result">
         <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
              <div style="width:50%;float:left;"><xsl:call-template name="SingleResult"/></div>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
              <div style="width:50%;float:right;"><xsl:call-template name="SingleResult"/></div>            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I end up with
1 
    2
3
    4

Any suggestions on how to get the results
1 | 2
3 | 4

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted includes the following after the right column

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Is this perhaps making your content wrap since you have the widths of your first two divs set to 50%.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 100%">    
 <xsl:for-each select="All_Results/Result">
   <div style="width:50%;float:left;"><xsl:call-template name="SingleResult"/></div>
 </xsl:for-each>
<div>
```

Assuming there is no other styling then this should work fine as it will fill the container div with two at 50% and then wrap to the next line.  What you are seeing is what usually happens if you have some padding or margin which means that two divs at 50% are actually more than the 100% outer div.