# How to split people search result into 2 columns?

Tags: xslt

I followed this discussion. The suggested post by David works only if the sort by is not present. If I have sort in the xslt or if I use the built in sort functionality after the page is rendered then the format is still 2 columns but the rows heights are all messed up. Any idea?

[How to distribute People Search Core Results over two columns using XSL redux](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70623/how-to-distribute-people-search-core-results-over-two-columns-using-xsl-redux)

```
<div style="width: 100%">    
 <xsl:for-each select="All_Results/Result">
   <div style="width:50%;float:left;"><xsl:call-template name="SingleResult"/></div>
 </xsl:for-each>
<div>
```